# jquery - showing hidden fields based on selected radio button

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have several radio inut fields, that have specific values, that, when selected, I'd like to show an input field, so my code is:

```
        <label for="adult">Adult</label>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="45" />
        <label>Number</label><input type="text" id="dob"  />

        <label for="adult">Student</label>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="5" />
        <label>D.O.B</label><input type="text" id="dob"  />

        <label for="adult">Child</label>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="5" />
        <label>D.O.B</label><input type="text" id="dob"  />
```

You can see both the `Student` and the `Child` button have a `D.O.B` field. I need this to be hidden and only display if the selected radio is chosen.

My biggest problem, is that both have the same `value` (this is based on a price, which are the same).

How would I target each specific radio to show the `D.O.B` field? Could I add a class/id to each and target them that way?

Thanks

Comment: you are right ...access them by class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: IDs should be unique (multiple `id="dob"` are bad)

To answer your question: Give each input to show/hide a class (here: `dob`) and each radio button, which has a dob-field another one (here: `show_dob`). Then you can do:

```
<script type="text/js">
$( function() {

    $('input.dob').hide(); // hide all first
    $('input[type="radio"]').click( function() {
        $('input.dob').hide(); // hide all on click
        if( $(this).hasClass('show_dob') ) { // only if the radio button has a dob-field
            $(this).nextAll('input.dob:first').show(); // show only the following first
        }
    });

});
</script>

    <label for="adult">Adult</label>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="45" />
    <label>Number</label><input type="text" />

    <label for="adult">Student</label>
    <input class="show_dob" type="radio" name="type" value="5" />
    <label>D.O.B</label><input class="dob" type="text" />

    <label for="adult">Child</label>
    <input class="show_dob" type="radio" name="type" value="5" />
    <label>D.O.B</label><input class="dob" type="text" />
```

Comment: What if i was to put the form elements in a table, i.e.: `<table><tr><td><label for="adult">Adult</label></td><td><input type="radio" name="type" value="45" /></td><td><label class="lhidden">Number</label><input type="text" class="dob ihidden"/></td></tr></table> it doesn't seem to work when I move it into a table. It only seems to show/hide the first `dob` field when I select any of the 2 `dob` fields

Comment: take a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ and http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/. Study some examples and you will learn to solve such problems by yourself. Try it and open a new question if you get stuck again, but you will be able to solve your comment yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <script>
       $(document).ready(
       function()
       {
           $('input').click(
           function()
           {
               $(this).next().next().attr('value', $(this).attr('value'));
           });
       });
</script>

</head>
<body style="font-size: 62.5%;">
    <label for="adult">Adult</label>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="45" />
        <label>Number</label><input type="text" id="dob"  />

        <label for="adult">Student</label>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="5" />
        <label>D.O.B</label><input type="text" id="dob"  />

        <label for="adult">Child</label>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="5" />
        <label>D.O.B</label><input type="text" id="dob"  />
</body>
```

Comment: That doesn't show/hide the input's when a radio button is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Add marker classesl. class = “studentVisible “ and class ="childVisible “

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(
       function()
       {
           $('input').click(
           function()
           {
               $("[id$='dob']").attr('value', $(this).attr('value'));
           });
       });
</script>

</head>
<body style="font-size: 62.5%;">
    <label for="adult">Adult</label>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="45" />
        <label>Number</label>

        <label for="adult">Student</label>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="5" />
        <label>D.O.B</label>

        <label for="adult">Child</label>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="5" />
        <label>D.O.B</label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="dob"  />
</body>
```

Only one textbox showing as per click

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

You need to chage small your HTML structure:

**HTML**

```
        <label for="adult">Adult</label>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="45" />
        <label class="lhidden">Number</label><input type="text" class="dob ihidden"/>

        <label for="adult">Student</label>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="5" />
        <label class="lhidden">D.O.B</label><input type="text" class="dob ihidden"/>

        <label for="adult">Child</label>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="5" />
        <label class="lhidden">D.O.B</label><input type="text" class="dob ihidden"/>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() {
    $('.ihidden,.lhidden').hide();
    $('input[type="radip"]').attr('checked', '');
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
        $('input[type="radio"]:visible').attr('checked', '');
        $('.ihidden:visible, .lhidden:visible').hide();
        $(this).attr('checked', 'checked').next().show().next().show();
    });
});
```

If not work please comment me.